# Compare two columns and highlight the text if it contains the text from first column

Tags: excel, comparison

I have two columns

```
A                      |  B
--------------------------------------
123 main street        |  123
234 cello street       |  456
449 w 3rd street       |  585
1098 folsom blvd       |  1098
2323 new york street   |  1088
676 cherry street      |  676
```

My question is, Is there any chance we can compare Columns A and B and find out, If the value of Column B is in Column A. We are not comparing the whole text, but only a part of Column A with whole Column B.

*Note: * I'm sure combination of two cells from Column B will not be there in A for example, 123456 will not be there in Column A.

Comment: Looks like that would work, @pnuts.  My solution is a bit more cumbersome!

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(SEARCH(B1;A1;1);1;0)
```

Will get you a 1 if the text is present and a 0 if it is not. Is that what you want?

Comment: But, instead of doing one by one can I select all from B and compare with each element of A?
Sounds like a java program.
Or pick one from B and compare with all the values of A.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most high-performance way, but there's a convenient VBA function for converting a range to a CSV, and it's here.  (Press Alt+F11 on to access VBA developer, and put this into a new module):

```
'**********************************************
'* PURPOSE: Concatenates range contents into a
'*          delimited text string
'*
'* FUNCTION SIGNATURE: Range2Csv(Range, String)
'*
'* PARAMETERS:
'*    Range  - the range of cells whose contents
'*             will be included in the CSV result
'*    String - delimiter used to separate values
'*             (Optional, defaults to a comma)
'*
'* AUTHOR: www.dullsharpness.com
'**********************************************
Public Function Range2Csv(inputRange As Range, Optional delimiter As String)
  Dim concattedList As String 'holder for the concatted CSVs
  Dim rangeCell As Range      'holder cell used in For-Each loop
  Dim rangeText As String     'holder for rangeCell's text

  'default to a comma delimiter if none is provided
  If delimiter = "" Then delimiter = ","

  concattedList = ""          'start with an empty string

  'Loop through each cell in the range to append valid contents
  For Each rangeCell In inputRange.Cells

    rangeText = rangeCell.Value 'capture the working value

    'Only operate on non-blank cells (i.e. Length > 0)
    If Len(rangeText) > 0 Then
      'Strip any delimiters contained w/in the value itself
      rangeText = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(rangeText, delimiter, "")

      If (Len(concattedList) > 0) Then
        'prepend a delimiter to the new value if we
        'already have some list items
        concattedList = concattedList + delimiter + rangeText
      Else
        'else if the list is blank so far,
        'just set the first value
        concattedList = rangeText
      End If
    End If

  Next rangeCell

  'Set the return value
  Range2Csv = concattedList

End Function
```

Assuming the range you want to search against is `A1:A20`, you can highlight the search term cells (starting with cell `B1` in this example) and enter this Conditional formatting formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,range2csv($A$1:$A$20,";")))
```

This will work by first making a string of all of your search targets (it concatenates each cell into a contiguous string), and then checking one by one whether the search term (column B entry) exists in the concatenated string.

As stated, it's probably not the most performant way to do this, but it's a quick solution.

[Range2Csv Function Writeup](http://dullsharpness.com/2011/11/14/excel-vba-range-to-csv-range2csv-function/)